# What is the "SYS_C00054_14031410:34:03$" column in my regular Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Tried to do partition exchange and it failed because of 2 extra SYS_* columns in the table:

```
select NAME from SYS.COL$ WHERE obj# =41900658 and name like 'SYS_%';

SYS_C00054_14031410:34:03$
SYS_C00055_14031410:34:03$
```

ALL_TAB_COLUMNS show nothing on these

What are these? and why CTAS didn't pick them up?

If `extended stats` - how do i drop them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unused columns.

```
SQL> create table t1 as select * from dba_roles;

Table created.

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ROLE                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 PASSWORD_REQUIRED                                  VARCHAR2(8)
 AUTHENTICATION_TYPE                                VARCHAR2(11)

SQL> alter table t1 set unused (AUTHENTICATION_TYPE);

Table altered.

SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ROLE                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 PASSWORD_REQUIRED                                  VARCHAR2(8)

SQL> select column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'T1';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C00003_18012517:25:39$
PASSWORD_REQUIRED
ROLE

SQL> alter table t1 drop unused columns;

Table altered.

SQL> select column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'T1';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
PASSWORD_REQUIRED
ROLE
```

Edit:

Extra information: I used `*_TAB_COLS`, because `*_TAB_COLUMNS` does not list such columns.

Comment: great, thank you. how do i get the real hidden column name? any way to select from "SYS_"?

Comment: @olekb The moment you set it to unused, it's renamed to a system-generated name, and you lost that information. In my example, it is still possible to retreive the column name with flashback query, but your columns were set to unused almost 4 years ago based on the timestamp in the column name, so that is not possible in your case.